# What is best way to update product stock (inventory) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, inventory

I have some question about how to calculate product quantity.
Let say I have 3 tables

```
product table
product_id | name | stock

stock-in table
stock_in_id | product_id | qty

stock-out table
stock_out_id | product_id | qty
```

So, I want to update my stock in product table, how do I do that in MySQL ?

The one that comes in my mind is to sum all of my **stock in** table qty and then substract it with **stock out** table qty then using that query to update my stock in product table, but what if my database become too big to calculate all the data, will it become a problem ?

The other way that comes to my mind is using trigger everytime I create a new stock-in or stock-out, but how do I do that ? And what happen if I delete or edit a row in my table ?

Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: To me triggers make the most sense.  Prevent direct updates to the product table using triggers or security such that only the system account can update. write a nightly routine that audits the tables and reports on discrepancies.  Turn on auditing on the product table so you can trace the discrepancies if they arise.  You can truncate logs on a rotating cycle if needed.  All this will require some research on your part; but it is an approach

Comment: Another approach would be to store the last updated date in product and only parse transactions after that date to update

Comment: Normally qty would be in product table and stock in and stock out would be transactions that 'explained' why qty was that value. ie qty should =  the sum of all stock that came in - all the stock that went out.

Comment: and I agree w/ tony.  Qty should be on the product table.  I missed the fact it was missing.  It's a Summary of the detail in the in/out table.  You may not even need an in/out table if you just have a "Status" on the record" and call it "Stock_transactions" or something.  If performance becomes a problem, you can always partition the table by year and the status and/or other criteria depending on reporting needs.

Comment: well, stock mean sum of qty in - sum of qty out. So if I want to know the qty of my a product for example, I just looked at product table.

Comment: Stock in transaction cans then be recociled with purchase orders and them with invoices. Stock out with reqisitioning. The you can do future requistions and with an expected stock level, start doing net requirements planning. Also you can build in stockcheck functionality.